# Borel subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: matrices, reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

As the title indicates, I want to ask what is the Borel subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$? I believe I read about it in one of James Milne's notes. But now I cannot find it. That is why I want to ask.

Comment: Hmm... $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is discrete. So Borel subgroup basically means a subgroup...

Comment: If you ask what's a Borel subgroup in general. This is just a subgroup that is measurable with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. (Have you done measure-theory, if not, read about Borel sets in general).

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(B,_N)_pair and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iwasawa_decomposition for the motivation of Borel subgroups (to obtain a decomposition of $G$ in simpler subgroups)

Comment: @Yanko I would guess that the OP means Borel subgroup to be the concept from algebraic groups, though I am not certain if extra care is needed when not working over a field. But presumably the upper triangular matrices will still be a Borel subgroup and we just also might have more than usual.